# ASP.NET Image Resizing and Cropping

Tags: asp.net, iis, compression, crop, imageresizer

I m looking for ASP.NET Image Resizing, Cropping
that is good in image re-sizing, cropping etc.
Anyone know please share

Thankx In Advance

Comment: You already have GDI+, why do you need something else?

Comment: because 3rd party API do best as compare to GDI. they have embedded croping algorithms etc which give you the exact image that u expect!

Comment: What's so hard about cropping? Just create a `Bitmap` and copy part of the original image with `DrawImage`. What exactly does GDI+ fail to provide?

Comment: [These pitfalls](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/) are why it's safer to use a library than write your own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well Experts!!!
Last day I found http://www.imageresizing.net/ and its great. and good API. Works Great.
Downloaded from Visual studio 2010 Extension Manager: http://nuget.org/.

Easy Steps to download API in VS-2010:

**1). Install Extension http://nuget.org/.**
[image]
**3). Find and Install ImageResizing**
[image]

**4).Then Code: (I m using here cropping. you can use any) Documentation on imageresizing.net**

```
string uploadFolder = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath + "images/");
FileUpload1.SaveAs(uploadFolder + FileUpload1.FileName);


//The resizing settings can specify any of 30 commands.. See http://imageresizing.net for details.
ResizeSettings resizeCropSettings = new ResizeSettings("width=200&height=200&format=jpg&crop=auto");

//Generate a filename (GUIDs are safest).
string fileName = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

//Let the image builder add the correct extension based on the output file type (which may differ).
fileName = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(uploadFolder + FileUpload1.FileName, fileName, resizeCropSettings, false, true);
```

Try!!! its very awsumm and easy to use. thanks.

Comment: Hi Muhammad. Would I be able to use this tool if I have a hosted website (i.e. GoDaddy, etc)? That is to say, I can not walk over to the main server and install this component, as I do not own the server.

Comment: @jp2code, Hello, Yes you can use it on like GoDaddy type website mean where you cannot walk over to the main server and install component like ASPJPEG(in old version which I hv used).

Its working fine for me on shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the resizing you need: [C# Tutorial - Image Editing: Saving, Cropping, and Resizing](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing). As far as compression, that is going to be a function of the image format you choose e.g., PNG, JPG, GIF. To take control of that, look at the sample code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx). Once you've saved to a compressed format, any further compression is (generally) a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need a DLL for that. They are just three functions. Resizing, Cropping and Compression.

Its pretty much covered at [Image resizing, cropping and compression using .NET](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/05/image-resizing-cropping-and-compression.html)

The only area that need some innovation is the area of cropping where one might need to visually crop images. For that use

1. [Image ASP.NET](http://nhachothue.codeplex.com/) ( [Demo here](http://nhachothue.net/cropimages/) )
2. [Upload and Crop Images with jQuery, JCrop and ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/95/Upload-and-Crop-Images-with-jQuery-JCrop-and-ASP.NET)

Comment: I disagree. There are [over 29 pitfalls, and nobody ever avoids them all](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/). The blog you're linking to uses a poor resampling algorithm and will cause a border artifact around the entire image, in addition to doing the cropping math incorrectly. I'm still waiting to see a single article on resizing that does everything right. At least the article you linked to doesn't seem to leak memory like most examples do. When it's this difficult to do a (seemingly) simple thing right, [a library is a good idea](http://imageresizing.net).